# Change style for element from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to uniqeley identify buttons in a tablerow, so I can change the style if one of them is clicked. Here is the table i am working on:

[image: table]

And here is the code:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Allergi navn</th>
            <th>Allergi verdi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="items in $ctrl.allergen">
            <td>
                <b>
                    {{items.Allergennavn}}
                </b>
            </td>
            <td id="{{$index}}">
                <button 
                    id="tableButton" 
                    type="button" 
                    class="btn-grey"  
                    ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.allergenVerdiType"
                    ng-click="$ctrl.allergiAssigned($index, items, item)"
                >
                <b>
                    {{item.Allergenverdi}}
                </b>
                </button>
                <hr>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And js:

```
ctrl.allergiAssigned = function($index, itemAllergen, itemAllergenType){
        var index = $('button').index(this);
        $(index, '#tableButton').css("background-color", "green");           
    }
```

I have tried several approaches to reference the specific button-element, using this, index, etc. I also need to verfiy that for every row, there is only one of the buttons that are selected.

I also tried to pass `{{$index}}` to get a unique identifier for the row, but jquery doesn't support the syntax.

UPDATE based on answers:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Allergi navn</th>
            <th>Allergi verdi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="items in $ctrl.allergen">
              <td>
                  <b>
                      {{items.Allergennavn}}
                  </b>
              </td>
              <td id="{{$index}}">
                  <button id="tableButton" type="button" 
                      class="btn-grey" ng-class="{activeBtn: item.active == true}"
                      ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.allergenVerdiType"
                      ng-click="$ctrl.select(items.type, item)">
                  {{item.AllergenverditypeKode}}</button>
                  <hr>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>

  ctrl.select = function(items, index) {
        angular.forEach(items, function(item){
          item.active=false;
        });
        index.active = true;
    };
```

index returns undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can change the CSS class based on the user action by using ng-class directive.
[details](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Code will be like that.
In CSS class :`.activeButton:{background-color", "green"}`

In button ng-click function : `buttonClicked[$index]=true;`

In Html button input:

```
.....  ng-class="{'btn-grey':'btn-grey',                      
        'activeButton':<add your condition like 'buttonClicked[$index]'>}"
```

Answer (score 1):

To uniquely identify an element in nested `ng-repeat`, you can assign a unique `Id` to it by combining the `$index` from the `parent` loop and from the `child` loop as :

```
id="tableButton_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}"
```

Now, pass the `parent index` and the `child index` to the event, fetch the element and change its css:

`ng-click="assigned($parent.$index, $index)"`

Below is a snippet of a sample data:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ["Item A", "Item B"];
  $scope.buttonTypes = ["Btn1", "Btn2", "Btn3", "Btn4"];

  $scope.assigned = function(parentIndex, childIndex) {
    //Reset all buttons for one row
    var parentBtns = "#" + parentIndex + " :button";
    $(parentBtns).css("background", "transparent");
    
    //Change the selected button css
    var btn = "#tableButton_" + parentIndex + "_" + childIndex;
    $(btn).css("background", "green");
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Allergi navn</th>
        <th>Allergi verdi</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>
          <b>{{item}}</b>
        </td>
        <td id="{{$index}}">
          <button id="tableButton_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" type="button" class="btn-grey" ng-repeat="type in buttonTypes" ng-click="assigned($parent.$index, $index)">
                <b>{{type}}</b>
                </button>
          <hr>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the below code, also you check you given working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tkcyNjatj33wO22rga0q?p=preview) example.

Template:

```
<button id="tableButton" type="button" class="defaultBtn" ng-class="{activeBtn: item.active}" ng-repeat="item in items.type" ng-click="select(items.type, item)">{{item.value}}</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.select= function(items, index) {
    // You can remove this loop part if you don't want to reset your selection..
    angular.forEach(items, function(item){
      item.active=false;
    });
    index.active = true;
};
```

Comment: i updataed my question based on your answer, but I'm still having trouble with the js

Comment: @Immanuel ng-class="{activeBtn: item.active}" is enough .No need to check again like 'item.active == true'

Comment: Yeah, you are right @KannanThangadurai. I've updated. :)

Comment: @ØysteinSeel, You needs to change **$ctrl.select(items.type, item)** to **$ctrl.select($ctrl.allergenVerdiType, item)** where you are till passing first parameter as my example variable..